# Pandas Dataframe Invalid Key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df.loc[(df['Original Price'] != '0') & (df['Old Original Price'] != '0'), 'Price Difference'].index = df['Original Price'] - df['Old Original Price']
```

I am currently trying to compare two columns of the dataframe and if their value is not equal to 0 they will make a new column and do a subtraction between the two values

although I seem to keep obtaining the error mentioned below:

```
TypeError: '(Series([], dtype: bool), 'Price Difference')' is an invalid key
```

Comment: Seems like you're missing `loc` . You can't select both index and columns without `loc` or `iloc`-> `df.loc[(df['Original Price'] != '0') & (df['Old Original Price'] != '0'), 'Price Difference'] = df['Original Price'] - df['Old Original Price']`

Comment: Yea i tried that but the thing is they need the key for this and my intention is to gather all those in the column "original price" and "old original price" that is != 0. Hence, I am unable to specify a specific row

Comment: What about the code snippet in my comment does not work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
df.loc[((df['Original Price'] != '0') & (df['Old Original Price'] != '0')),'Price_Difference'] = df['Original Price'] - df['Old Original Price']
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to see a sample of how your data looks, and what are the data types of your columns, but based on what you mentioned, here is what I suggest:

```
df['Price Difference']= df['Original Price']
df.loc[((~df['Original Price'].isin(['0'])) & (~df['Old Original Price'].isin(['0']))), 'Price Difference']= df['Original Price'] - df['Old Original Price']
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
df[Price Difference] =df.apply(function,axis=1)
```

And write logic in method

```
function(row):
    {
    if (row['Original Price'] != '0') & (row['Old Original Price'] != 
     '0'):
     return row['Original Price'] - row['Old Original Price']
     }
```

Comment: This is not how functions are defined in python. DataFrame.apply will also not handle non-return as setting with enlargement you'll need to handle all cases if applying iteratively.

Comment: Please share sample of your data.